Filter XML via XLST based on different submodes
I have an xml with Users that can have multiple changes a day - this is represented by sequence numbers. Therefore I have the following XML:
<userValues>
    <user>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <startDate>20241013</startDate>
        <someValue>200</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>1</sequenceNr>
    </user>
    <user>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <startDate>20241013</startDate>
        <someValue>500</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>2</sequenceNr>
    </user>
    <user>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <startDate>20241001</startDate>
        <someValue>200</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>1</sequenceNr>
    </user>
    <user>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <startDate>20241001</startDate>
        <someValue>200</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>1</sequenceNr>
    </user>
</userValues>

This would need to be filtered so I get the following result:
<userValues>
    <user>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <startDate>20241013</startDate>
        <someValue>500</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>2</sequenceNr>
    </user>
    <user>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <startDate>20241001</startDate>
        <someValue>200</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>1</sequenceNr>
    </user>
    <user>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <startDate>20241001</startDate>
        <someValue>200</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>1</sequenceNr>
    </user>
</userValues>

so basically I need for each user the highest sequenceNumber - but to be honest I am not even sure if XSLT can do that for me (but would save a lot of coding if possible)
I can get the XML sorted by ID, startDate and sequenceNr before entering the XSLT processing.
Since I don't really know XSLT yet (basically I am starting to learn it now...) I would like to know if it is possible and - if so - how?

XSLT is turing complete, so yes, everything is possible. And as you know, we usually expect you to show some minimum attempt to solve it yourself.

This is a grouping question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers for XSLT 1.0 are different from those for XSLT 2.0 or higher.

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Please try the following solution based on XSLT 2.0 or later.
Input XML
<userValues>
    <user>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <startDate>20241013</startDate>
        <someValue>200</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>1</sequenceNr>
    </user>
    <user>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <startDate>20241013</startDate>
        <someValue>500</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>2</sequenceNr>
    </user>
    <user>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <startDate>20241001</startDate>
        <someValue>200</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>1</sequenceNr>
    </user>
    <user>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <startDate>20241001</startDate>
        <someValue>200</someValue>
        <sequenceNr>1</sequenceNr>
    </user>
</userValues>

XSLT 2.0
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"
                omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/userValues">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="user" group-by="ID">
                <xsl:variable name="max-sequenceNr"
                              select="max(current-group()/sequenceNr/xs:int(.))"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[sequenceNr=$max-sequenceNr]"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<userValues>
  <user>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <startDate>20241013</startDate>
    <someValue>500</someValue>
    <sequenceNr>2</sequenceNr>
  </user>
  <user>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <startDate>20241001</startDate>
    <someValue>200</someValue>
    <sequenceNr>1</sequenceNr>
  </user>
  <user>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <startDate>20241001</startDate>
    <someValue>200</someValue>
    <sequenceNr>1</sequenceNr>
  </user>
</userValues>

